# Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on an Android application in Android Studio and I'm struggling to get my new fragment to display. In the logcat I see an error but I'm not sure what it means and can't find the answer to this issue anywhere else. I'm not sure if I'm making other errors in trying to set up this fragment.

I've tried only adding the fragment programmatically but found other examples on YouTube of adding the fragment to XML so I've tried that too and it didn't work either. I've been trying to work this out for days so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried starting the new fragment using fragmentTransaction.add and fragmentTransaction.replace with no difference.

Here is the main class

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button menuButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        menuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_button);

        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startClassMenu();

            }
        });
    }

    public void startClassMenu(){

        Fragment classMenuFragment = new ClassMenuFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.class_menu_fragment_place, classMenuFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Here is the main class xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/menu_button"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_blue_menu" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_button"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/home_icon" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/settings_button"
    android:layout_width="37dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/menu_button"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_settings" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/class_menu_fragment_place"
    android:name="teamingenium.ingeniummobileapplication.fragments.ClassMenuFragment"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="187dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/menu_button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-127dp" />
```

Here is the fragment Java class

```
public class ClassMenuFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_class_menu, container, false);

    return view;

}
}
```

And here is the fragment xml class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ClassMenuFragment"
     android:id="@+id/fragment_class_menu">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_class_menu_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:text="Fragment Started" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the error from logcat

```
2018-12-29 20:09:48.405 1925-1925/system_process E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/GoogleSdkSetup/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
```

Comment: May be it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700486/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-app-corecomponentfactory

Answer (score 1):

refer to this link [fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating)；

As you use `<fragment` in your  layout xml, you have no need to invoke `startClassMenu()` ,just to delete the `startClassMenu()` method and try again.

Try other two methods:

1, try to use `android.app.Fragment` and `android.app.FragmentManager` and `android.app.Activity` instead of  using support library.

2, try to add `-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.**` in your `proguard-rules.pro` file

Answer (score 0):

Try these

After checking this "DexPathList", it is definitely due to dexes.

multidex increases the number of methods

`The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536`

This error can be caused due to using both androidx and legacy android support libraries

Just open project structure and go to Dependencies and select All Modules and check is there any library which contains `android.support`

Just replace that with androidx version for that library

If still that issue exists then

Try these to fix this issue

```
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
}
```

in the latest versions of android studio, just `REMOVE` these lines if it is there inside the manifest file

```
<application
...
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"  // REMOVE THIS
android:appComponentFactory="androidx"       // REMOVE THIS
>
```

Check for this line

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Add this line in your MainActivity.kt

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)  //ADD THIS
    }
}
```

Add this in your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class com.example.** { *; }
```

Verify in this

```
 buildTypes {
        dev{
            minifyEnabled false
             }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
             }
    }
```

In latest version of android studio there is no `instant run` disable options

Now android studio requires jdk versions above 8 so `NO NEED` TO ADDING THIS

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```