# "Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory" I tried it in many ways, but I get the same error

Tags: java, android

I keep getting an error when running the app.

Error content.

```
E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mopius.samsung.cnt.pt2.user.whateverString" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mopius.samsung.cnt.pt2.user-DAObBSssK56o1gzvrv8Oog==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mopius.samsung.cnt.pt2.user-DAObBSssK56o1gzvrv8Oog==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:273)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:896)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:991)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1248)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2618)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2610)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6900)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2064)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8034)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

The methods i tried

1. AndroidManifest.xml Add the line

   tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
   android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
2. proguard-rules.pro Add the line

   -keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory{*;}

I've tried, but I keep getting the same error.
Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Try this, It helped me to resolve my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/74523286/6236959

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and fixed it by changing 
 the multidex dependency from `support` to `androidx` like this: 

<del>implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'</del>

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Don't forget to add this in defaultConfig:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```